# How can I make a separate class for a fire ball in my code?

Tags: java, image, class, animation, sprite

My code currently works, with that said I would like to make a separate class for the fire ball. I don't know how to do this and i cant find any examples I am just looking for help on deriving a separate class so that my main code is not so large. Here is code:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
public class Main extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{
    ImageIcon images[], imagesL[],standingImage[],punchImg[],
            fireImg[],kickImg[],jumpImg[],slamImg[];
    int x = 100, y = 530;
    int count;
    int velX,velY;
    int velF;
    int firey,firex;
    int gravity = 20;
    int totalImages =3, currentImage = 0, animationDelay = 80,
            numSlam = 3,currentSlam = 0, numberImages = 1,
            currentStand = 0,
            numPunch = 3, currentPunch = 0;

    int currentFire = 0, numFire =1,totalImagesL =3,
            currentImageL =     0,currentKick = 0, numKick=2,currentJump = 0,
            numJump = 1;
    int height, totalHeight = -120;
    int  velEnemy = 5;
    int counter;
    int enemyX = 310;
    Timer animationTimer;
    boolean isMovingLeft;
    boolean isKick;
    boolean isFire = false, fireIs = false,isMovingRight = false,
            isNotMoving = true, isPunch = false, startFire = false, isJump = false,
            isSlam = false;
    boolean  enemyIsDead = false;
    Image fireball;
    Image back;
    Image title;
    Image alien;
    long lastJumptime = 0;
    long lastrJumptime = 0;
    long currentTime;
    long lastFiretime = 0;
    private final int FRAME_DELAY = 50;
    public Main() {
        setFocusable(true); // make your panel focusable
        addKeyListener(this); // register the key listener
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        //WALKING/RUNNING RIGHT//
        images = new ImageIcon[totalImages];
        images[2] = new ImageIcon("standing.png");
        images[1] = new ImageIcon("midWay.png");
        images[0] = new ImageIcon("running.png");
        //WALKING/RUNNING LEFT//
        imagesL = new ImageIcon[totalImagesL];
        imagesL[2] = new ImageIcon("standingL.png");
        imagesL[1] = new ImageIcon("midWayL.png");
        imagesL[0] = new ImageIcon("runningL.png");
        ///STANDING STILL
        standingImage = new ImageIcon[numberImages];
        standingImage[0] = new ImageIcon("standing.png");
        //PUNCH/////
        punchImg = new ImageIcon[numPunch];
        punchImg[0] = new ImageIcon("midPunch.png");
        punchImg[1] = new ImageIcon("punchFull.png");
        punchImg[2] = new ImageIcon("midPunch.png");
        //COMMENCE FIREBALL//
        fireImg = new ImageIcon[numFire];
        fireImg[0] = new ImageIcon("startFire.png");
        //COMMENCE KICK//
        kickImg = new ImageIcon[numKick];
        kickImg[0]= new ImageIcon("startKick.png");
        kickImg[1]= new ImageIcon("finishKick.png");
        //JUMPING//
        jumpImg = new ImageIcon[numJump];
        jumpImg[0] = new ImageIcon("ready.png");
        //TITLE THINGY///
        ImageIcon title = new ImageIcon("gokuTitle.png");
        //SLAM THINGY//
        slamImg = new ImageIcon[numSlam];
        slamImg[0] = new ImageIcon("startSlam.png");
        slamImg[1] = new ImageIcon("midSlam.png");
        slamImg[2] = new ImageIcon("endSlam.png");
        startAnimation();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //SOUND FOR THIS STUFF//
        Sound[] soundSelection = new Sound[4];
        soundSelection[0]= new Sound("Fire Spell.wav");
        soundSelection[1] = new Sound("kick effect.wav");
        soundSelection[2] = new Sound("fire ball troll.wav");
        soundSelection[3] = new Sound("punch sound effect.wav");
        //END STUFF FOR SOUND//
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics g2 = (Graphics) g;
        try{
            back = ImageIO.read(new File("backGround.png"));
            title = ImageIO.read(new File("gokuTitle.png"));
        }catch (IOException e) {
        }
        g2.drawImage(back, 0, 0, null);
        g2.drawImage(title, 0, 0, null);
        if (isMovingRight == true){//if moving right
            if (images[currentImage].getImageLoadStatus() == MediaTracker.COMPLETE) {
                Image imgRun =  images[currentImage].getImage();
                g2.drawImage(imgRun, x, y, null);
                currentImage = (currentImage + 1) % totalImages;
            }
        }
        if (isMovingLeft == true){//if moving left
            if (imagesL[currentImageL].getImageLoadStatus() == MediaTracker.COMPLETE)
            {
                Image imgRunL =  imagesL[currentImageL].getImage();
                g2.drawImage(imgRunL, x, y, null);
                currentImageL = (currentImageL + 1) % totalImagesL;
            }
        }
        if (isNotMoving == true){//IF not moving
            if (standingImage[currentStand].getImageLoadStatus() == MediaTracker.COMPLETE) {
                Image imgStand = standingImage[currentStand].getImage();
                g2.drawImage(imgStand, x, y, null);
                currentStand = (currentStand + 1) % numberImages;
            }
        }
        if (fireIs== true){
            //Do a seperate class for fireball
            isFire = true;
            if (fireImg[currentFire].getImageLoadStatus() == MediaTracker.COMPLETE) {
                Image  fireMe = fireImg[currentFire].getImage();
                g2.drawImage(fireMe, x, y, null);
                currentFire = (currentFire+ 1) % numFire;
                soundSelection[0].play();
                soundSelection[2].play();
            }
            try{
                fireball = ImageIO.read(new File("fireball.png"));
            }catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        if(isFire ==true){
            fireIs = false;
            g2.drawImage(fireball, firex + 80, firey+30, null);
        }
        if(isPunch == true){
            if (punchImg[currentPunch].getImageLoadStatus() == MediaTracker.COMPLETE) {
                Image punchMe = punchImg[currentPunch].getImage();
                g2.drawImage(punchMe, x, y, null);
                currentPunch = (currentPunch+ 1) % numPunch;
                soundSelection[3].play();
            }
        }
        if(isKick == true){
            if (kickImg[currentKick].getImageLoadStatus() == MediaTracker.COMPLETE) {
                Image kickMe = kickImg[currentKick].getImage();
                g2.drawImage(kickMe, x, y, null);
                currentKick = (currentKick+ 1) % numKick;
                soundSelection[1].play();
            }
        }
        if (isJump == true){
            if (jumpImg[currentJump].getImageLoadStatus() == MediaTracker.COMPLETE) {
                Image jumpUp = jumpImg[currentJump].getImage();
                g2.drawImage(jumpUp,x, y+10, null);
                currentJump = (currentJump+ 1) % numJump;
            }
        }
        if (isSlam == true){
            if (slamImg[currentSlam].getImageLoadStatus() == MediaTracker.COMPLETE) {
                Image slamUp = slamImg[currentSlam].getImage();
                g2.drawImage(slamUp,x, y+10, null);
                currentSlam = (currentSlam+ 1) % numSlam;
            }
        }
        //ENEMY THAT DOES NOT WANT TO WORK//

        //draw rect here//
        Rectangle player = new Rectangle(x,y, 60,100);
        Rectangle enemies = new Rectangle(enemyX,530, 60,100);
        /////
        if (player.intersects(enemies)){
            enemyIsDead = true;
        }
        if (enemyIsDead == false){
            try{
                alien = ImageIO.read(new File("Alien1.png"));
            }catch (IOException e) {
            }
            g2.drawImage(alien, enemyX, 530, null);
        }


    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(FRAME_DELAY);
        } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
        x+=velX;
        height += velY;
        enemyX+=velEnemy;
        if (height >= totalHeight){
            y+=velY;
        }else{
            y+=gravity;
        }
        firex += velF;
        if (y < 2){
            y = 3;
        }
        if (y >530){
            y = 531;
        }
    }
    public void right(){
        velX = 20;
    }
    public void left(){
        velX = -20;
    }
    public void fire(){
        velF = 30;
    }
    public void jump(){
        velY = -30;
    }
    public void notMovingMethod(){
        isMovingRight = false;
        isNotMoving = true;
        isPunch = false;
        isMovingLeft = false;
        isKick  = false;
        isJump = false;
        isSlam = false;
    }
    public void everythingFalse(){
        isPunch = false;
        isNotMoving = false;
        isMovingRight = false;
        isMovingLeft = false;
        isKick  = false;
        isJump = false;
        isSlam = false;
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        //FIND OUT ABOUT COUNTER FOR ENEMIES NEARBY,LIKE IF AN ENEMY IS NEAR YOU FOR 
        2 SEC YOU LOSE HEALTH
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_Z){
            currentTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (currentTime >= lastFiretime + 5000){
                firex = x;
                firey = y;
                fire();
                fireIs = true;
                everythingFalse();
                lastFiretime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_P){
            System.out.println("Paused");
            stopAnimation();
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_A){
            left();
            everythingFalse();
            isMovingLeft = true;

        }

        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_F){
            everythingFalse();
            isPunch = true;
        }

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_D){
            right();
            everythingFalse();
            isMovingRight = true;
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_Q){
            everythingFalse();
            isKick  = true;
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_W){
            currentTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (currentTime >= lastJumptime + 1000){
                jump();
                everythingFalse();
                isJump = true;
                lastJumptime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_E){
            everythingFalse();
            isSlam = true;
        }
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
        int code = e.getKeyCode();

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_D){
            notMovingMethod();
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_P){
            startAnimation();
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_A){
            notMovingMethod();
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_Q){
            notMovingMethod();
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_F){
            notMovingMethod();
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_E){
            notMovingMethod();
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_Z){
            notMovingMethod();
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_W){
            currentTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (currentTime >= lastrJumptime + 1000){
                notMovingMethod();
                height = 0;
            }
            lastrJumptime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        velX = 0;
    }
    public void startAnimation() {
        if (animationTimer == null) {
            currentImage = 0;
            currentImageL = 0;
            currentStand = 0;
            currentPunch=0;
            currentFire = 0;
            currentKick = 0;
            currentJump = 0;
            currentSlam = 0;
            animationTimer = new Timer(animationDelay, this);
            animationTimer.start();
        } else if (!animationTimer.isRunning())
            animationTimer.restart();
    }

    public void stopAnimation() {
        animationTimer.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should indent your code

Comment: Check out using the MVC (Model, View, Controller) here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html. You may have to redo a large part of your code in the start, but breaking it up into multiple object (Controller, Fireball, Kick, etc.) will help in the long run. Check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html for help on creating classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm very glad you are asking how to use separate classes, because based on the code you posted you need them very badly. Not just for the fireball. For the sound, for the animations, for the player, for the enemy. Every class should have only one responsibility, which is something your code does not do but which would make it much more legible and maintainable.

To answer your question, create a new .java file with your new class, something like:

```
public class Fireball {
    public Fireball() {
        //do whatever you need to do in the constructor
    }

    //you can declare other methods of fireballs here
}
```

And then include it in your main class with an `import` statement.

More info on the Single Responsibility Principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

A basic overview of classes - the best place to start if you are just deciding to use different classes for the first time: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

Comment: I tried what you said but I am confused when it comes to actually implementing it into the main program to draw the picture. For example, how to I update the picture to move the character/fire ball(especially with keyListener)? Also, how to I move all the methods into the separate class? Also, thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Start with the fireball, move that into its own class. Put the images for the fireball into that class as well as the logic for drawing the fireball. Make a method like drawSelf(Graphics g) that does the logic for drawing a fireball. Make that method within the Fireball class. Then call that method from your main class. Also, if this did help please remember to upvote =]

Answer (score 0):

Top-level classes in Java are defined in separate files, which you can then import.

You can also embed classes within a class, e.g.

```
public class Main {
    public static class Fireball {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem appropriate to do that for your use case.